# How to get the URL in webpack - react application

Tags: java, reactjs, webpack, config

My question might be silly so please bear with me.

**Background** : I have a project which consists of multiple java solutions as BE and 1 react application as FE application. when we build the entire solution, a war file gets generated which we deploy on different servers to load the application.

**Requirement** : We need to create single war file irrespective of the env.

**Issue** : we cannot have separate build scripts and generate different war files, so creating config with different values will not work. the only option is to read the URL and use it. But it wont be available at the time of war generation.

**env1 URL** : https/abcdefg.com/abc/rma/....

**env2 URL** : https/abcdefg.com/def/rma/....

Till now, we kept *application_context* in env file, and were updating that as per the env we are deploying. I am not getting how do I update it without the access of the URL in webpack. And if it can be done in react application, how do I do it? As of now if I deploy env1 war file to env2 I get this error -

GET *https/abcdefg.com/abc/rma/script/react-app/vendor/js/index.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this problem.

First approach involves using `<base />` tag along with `document.write`. The idea is to generate a bundle without using any hard-coded URL. All the bundle scripts that are added to your `index.html` file (probably by [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)) should be relative URLs. The `index.html` file should have following code in the `head` tag.

```html
<head>

  <!-- VERY FIRST STATEMENT -->
  <script>
    const [_, appname] = window.location.pathname.split('/');

    // The trailing slash `/` is important.
    document.write(`<base href="/${appname}/" />`);
  </script>

  <!-- Auto injected by html-webpack-plugin -->
  <script src="rma/script/react-app/vendor/js/index.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

This will cause your `rma/script/react-app/vendor/js/index.min.js` to be loaded as `https/abcdefg.com/abc/rma/script/react-app/vendor/js/index.min.js` where `abc` is your application name parsed from the URL.

However, using `document.write` is anti-pattern and discouraged. But advantage is that you can make use of Webpack's hash or chuckhash for bundle names to easily bust cache for the script on each new deployment.

The second approach involves writing an async injector for your bundled scripts. In your `index.html`, add the following to head tag:

```html
<head>

  <!-- VERY FIRST STATEMENT -->
  <script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const [_, appname] = window.location.pathname.split('/');
      
      const script = document.createElement('script');

      // Use root relative `src` for the scripts
      script.src = `/${appname}/rma/script/react-app/vendor/js/index.min.js`;

      document.body.append(script);
    });

  </script>

</head>
```

The advantage is that this is cleaner approach. The downside is that, you will have slight momentary delay and you need to no upfront the name of the generated bundle file like `react-app/vendor/js/index.min.js` meaning you won't be able to use Webpack's `[hash]` or `[chunkhash]` [feature](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying second way but its not working. In place of index.html we have index.ejs and I am not able to convert the code in it. :(

Comment: Thank you so much, After tweaking my .ejs file, I was able to convert it. Thanks so much again.